# Bash -- Rsync variable in filename has spaces

Tags: bash, variables, directory, rsync, spaces

Been searching for hours and still cant figure this out :(

Anyway, im creating a script that will automatically rsync about 40 different directories to 40 other directories on another server. if you want to see the entire script you can view it here: http://pastebin.com/Nt3KKvx9

But the important bit is the for loop where i run rsync

```
for ((i=0; i<${#websys[@]}; i++))
do
  localpath="/nusdata/staff/NUS/NUS/Systems/${kiskasys[$i]}"
  remotepath="/home/www/html/nusalaska.com/html/systems/${websys[$i]}"
  rsync -rlptnvz -s "$localpath" -e "ssh -p 50014" "nusak@webserver:$remotepath/"
done
```

The problem is that the array "kiskasys" has many directory names that have spaces in them (Example: '101 greenbrook'). 
I have tried making the array variables have single quotes around them, double quotes around them, escaped spaces like '\ ', and combinations of all three. I have also tried putting the $localpath in quotes, not in quotes, etc. etc.

I guess im just confused on how the -s (--protect-args) deals with the spaces and how I can get it to work in my situation.

The error output always looks something like the following:

```
rsync: change_dir "/nusdata/staff/NUS/NUS/101" failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

or

```
rsync: change_dir "/nusdata/staff/NUS/NUS/'101 greenbrook'" failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

### Found My Problem

In copying my code from my script to this page I accidently copied it wrong... however in copying it wrong, what i posted above was perfectly good code that works fine haha.

so what i posted above was the solution to my own problem.

The original had single quotes in the localpath variable like so:

```
localpath="'/nusdata/staff/NUS/NUS/Systems/${kiskasys[$i]}'"
```

and the single quotes was the problem. And for everyone's benefit here is an example output

```
echo ${kiskasys[1]}

#output would look like this:

101 greenbrook
```

Basically there are no special escape characters etc.

Comment: This is often the point at which you pull out a scripting language like Python or Ruby or something, which typically has better list handling and better handling of filenames with spaces.

Comment: @larsks -- I agree that a more powerful language might be the way to go at this point, although I think that judicious use of `find -print0` piped to `xargs -0` would probably work. I think that this will have to be done with `$localpath` as the current directory, in order to get the relative paths correct.

Comment: @KroniK907: I notice that your error messages show directories `/nusdata/staff/NUS/NUS/101` and `/nusdata/staff/NUS/NUS/'101 greenbrook'`, but your code above shows the local directory is under the `System` sub-directory of `/nusdata/staff/NUS/NUS/`. Could this be part of the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For what it's worth, I'm not able to replicate your problem.  If I set `localpath` and `remotepath` to a directory with spaces:

```
localpath="/home/lars/tmp/so/dir1/a directory"
remotepath="/home/lars/tmp/so/dir2/a directory"
```

And then run your `rsync` command (modified slightly for my environment):

```
rsync -rlptvz -s "$localpath/" -e "ssh" "localhost:$remotepath/"
```

It Just Works.  Here's the content of `dir1`:

```
dir1/a directory/file1
dir1/a directory/file3
dir1/a directory/file2
```

And after running rsync, `dir2` looks like this:

```
dir2/a directory/file1
dir2/a directory/file3
dir2/a directory/file2
```

Can you show a *specific* command line that results in the errors you're seeing above?  Maybe run the script with the `-x` flag and show exactly how `localpath` and `remotepath` are set.

Comment: Ok It turns out that in copying what I had in my script i accidentally copied it wrong, however what i copied was correct hahaha. The problem was that I had also put single quotes in the localpath variable on the inside of the double quotes. I hadn't noticed it until now and removed them and it worked perfect.