# Dealing with spaces in rsync path arguments

Tags: macos, bash, shell, path, rsync

So I'm currently trying to write a few small scripts that allow me to manage my iTunes library of which I have clones on multiple OS X machines.

The basic idea is that I have a NAS holding a copy of the library that is used as an intermediate "master copy" since the machines holding the actually used copies aren't available all the time. If I want to update my old copy on machine B with the newer version from machine A, I'd then update the NAS copy based on machine A's current state, then update machine B from the updated NAS copy possibly at a later time.

The script files are located on the NAS within the same folder that also houses the iTunes directory. Since I'm mounting the NAS as a volume via AFP, I simply open a Finder window with the directory containing the scripts and drag'n'drop the script I want to use to a Terminal window for easy execution.

This is my attempt at the "update NAS from local copy" script:

```
rsync -avz --compress-level 1 --exclude 'Mobile Applications/*.ipa' --delete --delay-updates -n "$(echo $HOME | sed 's/ /\\ /g')/Music/iTunes" "$(dirname $0 | sed 's/ /\\ /g')"
```

(`-n` option of course only for testing the script)

Since there will be spaces in the paths I supply `rsync` with, I already figured out that I'd need to escape those somehow. I also know that the standard way to do that on OS X is to prepend all the spaces with a backslash, at least when manually typing paths in Terminal. But the code above still won't work – `rsync` complains that it cannot change to the directory I supplied, although the path it spits out in the error message seems to be perfectly fine and can be `cd`'d to, if you remove the double quotes around it first:

```
[...]
building file list ... rsync: change_dir "/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Users/Julian/Music" failed: No such file or directory (2)
done
[...]
```

If I remove the surrounding double quotes in the script itself, `rsync` seems to not honor the escaping backslashes at all and still treat the space following the backslash as a path separator:

```
[...]
building file list ... rsync: link_stat "/Volumes/Macintosh\" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: change_dir "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/Julian/HD/Users/Julian/Music" failed: No such file or directory (2)
done
[...]
```

And no, I can't work around the issue by shortening `/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Users/Julian/Music` to `/Users/Julian/Music` since this machine has multiple HDDs and `/` is not the same disk/partition as `/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD`. So I need to find a solution for this specific problem.

I'm seriously lost now.

Can anyone please explain to me what I need to change in order to have `rsync` recognize the paths correctly?

Answer (score 0):

After messing around quite a bit more and finding [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909103/bash-rsync-variable-in-filename-has-spaces), I managed to develop a working solution:

```
localpath=$HOME/Music/iTunes
remotepath=$(dirname $0)/

rsync -avz \
    --compress-level 1 \
    --exclude 'Mobile Applications/*.ipa' \
    --delete \
    --delay-updates \
    -n \
    "$localpath" \
    "$remotepath"
```